# Conda Install Rasterio without Updating Dependencies

Tags: python, anaconda, rasterio

I am trying to install Rasterio to read a `.tif` image in my jupyter notebook. Normally I would just run `conda install -c forge rasterio` and then `y` to install the package, but I do not want to update any of the dependencies because if I do, the rest of my code breaks. I've never needed to not update my packages, so I am do not understand how to go about this issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using another virtual environment with Rasterio and its dependencies.

Comment: But if I need it for this specific environment???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent existing packages from updating, use the --freeze-installed option.

`conda install -c conda-forge rasterio --freeze-installed`

`conda install -c conda-forge rasterio --no-update-deps`

These two commands must work. For further knowledge you can visit [the official website](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html)